# Is it possible to use a file upload control to upload only image and video type of file at one time?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

```
    <div class="col-sm-6">

       <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload" runat="server" AllowMultiple="true" />
    </div>
```

Code behind:

```
 string ext = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(this.FileUpload.PostedFile.FileName);
   foreach (var file in FileUpload.PostedFiles)
     {
       if (ext == ".jpeg" || ext == ".png" || ext == ".bmp" || ext == ".jpg")
          {
            if (FileUpload.PostedFile.ContentLength > 0 && 
                             FileUpload.PostedFile.ContentLength <= 625000)
                  {.....
                      }

  else if (ext == ".mpeg4" || ext == ".mp4" || ext == ".3gp" || ext == ".flv")
  {
      if (FileUpload.PostedFile.ContentLength > 0 && FileUpload.PostedFile.ContentLength <= 625000)
     {.............................}
  }
```

The problem is when i upload 2 files 1 *.jpg file and other one is *.mp4 file then whatever i select first file in fileupload control it insert that file only which was selected first, and i want to insert both the files in different coloumn of the database table, i.e image path in image coloumn and video path in video coloumn.

I also tried `"string ext = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(this.FileUpload.PostedFile.FileName)"` under foreach loop then first it successfully insert the image file than again for second file loop start with taking .mp4 value and executing the If statement of the .jpg body. and insert the video path in image column.

I don't know why this if statement of .jpg is executing even after checking that the file is .mp4 This is the problem, I am facing.

NOTE: When I debug the code string ext takes .jpg extension , after that in `foreach` loop the second file came of .mp4 format then still ext contains .jpg .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo. Just access filename from your file variable on each iteration instead of only once before loop to get file extension.

Comment: ohh yeah sure, i forgot that . once again thnx Alott !